# How do I get ASP.Net (C#) AJAX to work nicely with this bit of jQuery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ASP.Net drop-down list. When a certain value is selected, I want some line breaks to show up. I'm doing this with jQuery because I don't know how to select a line break using ASP.Net. Thing is, I also have an UpdatePanel that is triggered with the same drop-down list. Can they work together?

ASP.Net:

```
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlHowMany" runat="server"  
                        onselectedindexchanged="ddlHowMany_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        style="margin-left: 8px" Width="50px" AutoPostBack="True" Height="22px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <br class="space" />
                        <br class="space" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGraphic1Desc" class="descriptions" runat="server" Height="92px" 
                            TextMode="MultiLine"
                            Width="260px" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Visible="False">Description of graphic #1</asp:TextBox>
                        <br class="space" />
                        <br class="space" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGraphic2Desc" class="descriptions" runat="server" Height="92px" 
                            TextMode="MultiLine"
                            Width="260px" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Visible="False">Description of graphic #2</asp:TextBox>
                        <br class="space" />
                        <br class="space" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtGraphic3Desc" class="descriptions" runat="server" Height="92px" 
                            TextMode="MultiLine"
                            Width="260px" Font-Names="Trebuchet MS" Visible="False">Description of graphic #3</asp:TextBox>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlHowMany" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

jQuery:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx",
            type: 'POST',
            complete: function () {
                if ($('#<%=ddlHowMany.ClientID %> option:selected').val() != "0") {
                    $('br.space').css({ display: 'block' });
                }
                else {
                    $('br.space').css({ display: 'none' });
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: Are you looking for an event to fire everytime an option is chosen in the select list?

Comment: No. For the ASP.Net, some textareas are supposed to display. There are line breaks between them, but I can't access them with ASP.Net. Is that even possible?

Comment: Are the breaks dynamic? could you run them at the server?

Comment: Why do you need line breaks specifically?  Are you trying to space the text boxes?  CSS is a MUCH better option for this and you won't have to fight this battle.  Either assign a CssClass (use this property instead of class) and assign a margin to it, or wrap each textbox in a div that properly margins or pads to the visual style you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your code using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()` instead of doing a POST with jQuery. Let `UpdatePanel` do the AJAX stuff and call jQuery after that.

Also note that you can't do a AJAX POST in ASP.NET WebForms with jQuery like this. You have to invoke `__doPostBack()` method or call `$(document.forms[0]).submit()` so that ASP.NET internal stuff can do its magic.

Comment: If I do this in other methods, will I need to use RegisterStartUpScript() or is that just for the first time?

Comment: RegisterStartupScript is used when you want something to be executed after the postback is done and the page is sent back to the client (either for the very first time or after a ajax or non-ajax postback).